# How can I transform types from a variadic argument before sending to std::vformat

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates, stdformat

I want to transform values of specific types coming from a variadic argument before sending it to std::vformat() but I can't seem to find a way to make it happen.

I tried getting the format arguments but I can't change it's value since the std::format_args::get() returns a const value.

Also tried to figure a way to unpack the variadic, transform the values and repack to be used by std::vformat().

I also tried overriding the formatter for basic types but that doesn't get used in the end.

```
#include <format>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
 

template <typename T>
inline void transform(T& valeur) {}
inline void transform(std::string& valeur) {
    valeur.append("abc");
}

inline void transformArgs() {}
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void transformArgs(T& t, Args&&... args) {

  transform(t);
  transformArgs(args...);
}


template <typename... Args>
std::string prepare(std::string requete, Args&&... args)
{
    //I want to add "abc" to any string-like values before using vformat
    std::format_args fmtargs = std::make_format_args(args...);

    const unsigned int nb = sizeof...(args);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nb; ++i) {

        auto arg = fmtargs.get(i);
        //Can't do anything with arg
    }

    transformArgs(args...);

  try {
    return std::vformat(requete, std::make_format_args(args...));
  }
  catch (...) {}

  return ""; 
}

int main() {

  char fixed[] {"banana"};
  auto result = prepare("{} - {} - {} - {}", 5, "litteral string", fixed, std::string("litteraly a string"));
  std::cout << result.c_str();

  /*
    I would expect this output : 
    5 - litteral stringabc - bananaabc - litteraly a stringabc
  */
}
```

Here's a sketch of my attempts
https://godbolt.org/z/red6654sf

Edit: Changed a thing to not get undefined behavior in the example.

Comment: Post code as text instead of link to code. Links may break in the future and also we have to go to an external site to just see the code when we can just see it here.

Comment: Current program produces different output in different runs. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qzvYEEx3q) You may have **undefined behavior** somewhere in your program.

Comment: You could just do it the way you phrased it in your question: transform types from a variadic argument **before** sending to `std::vformat` (emphasis mine)

Comment: I can't seem to think of a way to achieve this @Barry .  I know how to unpack, get every variable and know their types, but I don't know how to re-pack them somehow before sending to std::vformat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend changing the approach slightly, instead of having `transform` modify its argument, it should return a value that will replace in input.

So you can have a set of overloads like this:

```
std::string transform(std::string str) {
    return str.append("abc");
}
template<std::size_t N> std::string transform(const char(&arr)[N]) {
    return std::string{&arr[0], N - 1}.append("abc");
}
template<std::size_t N> std::string transform(char(&arr)[N]) {
    return std::string{&arr[0], N - 1}.append("abc");
}
template<typename T> T&& transform(T&& value) {
    return static_cast<T&&>(value);
}
```

And wrapp all the arguments in calls to `transform` when calling `make_format_args`:

```
return std::vformat(requete, std::make_format_args(transform(args)...));
```

[Example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7YKrn8YEG)

Comment: This looks good! I didn't know you could call transform for each argument in the pack using **transform(args)...**. Thanks for your time!

Comment: why not just `return std::format(requete, transform(args)...);`. `vformat` looks like something that OP believed is a good direction to to solve original problem to transform args before formatting output from them.